# Как запустить Evaluate Code Fragment в Intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, отладка

Как запустить Evaluate Code Fragment в Intellij IDEA (хочу выполнить произвольный код во время дебага)?
Пример: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ubjv.png
Не могу найти у себя такую опцию, может эта возможность доступная лишь в ULTIMATE версии?

Answer (score 3):

Вызвать Evaluate Expression вы можете сочетанием клавиш Alt+F8.
Дополнительную информацию по данному процессу вы можете найти [здесь](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/evaluating-expressions.html?search=evaluate).